# IF-Function with 3 variables within another function

Tags: excel

I have been trying to figure out an effective way to input an If-function into another formula and what I have seen online doesn't help me. I am new to this type of usage in Excel. Portion of the formula I want to replace with the IF-Function is highlighted. Essentially if `F5` is 1, the nper = 12, and if 2 than 24, and if 3 then 36.

What I have found online is this `=IF(F6>21,"Text 1",IF(E9<5,"Text 3","Text 2"))` but I can't figure out how to get this formula to work with what I want in the accompanying picture. [image: please see this screenshot of the spreadsheet] Please note that I left that code as I found it online, for the sake of not making any assumptions. Also I am not adverse to using a different method such as vlookup.

Thank-you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to calculate the number of monthly periods based on the number of years in the F column.

Rather than using a vlookup or nested IF statements, just calculate the number of months by multiplying the number of years by 12:

```
=PMT($B$22,F5*12,E5,0)
```

Comment: That's a great idea...I have no idea why I didn't think of that. Thank-you. Now out of sheer curiousity is there a way to do it using vlookup or nested IF statements? I have a feeling knowing that would come in handy in the future.

Comment: If you know that only 3 options are available, you can use the nested IF statement that you found: IF(F5=1,12,IF(F5=2,24,36))

Comment: Just one final quick question - why did you format the function like <<IF(F5=1,12,IF(F5=2,24,36)) >> as opposed to detailing what the function is to do IF F5 = 3, 36...I don't know how to write that into the code you wrote. So please bear with my poor attempt at explanation. 

Like this perhaps? IF(F5=1,12,IF(F5=2,24,IF(F5=3,36)))

Comment: Because, IF you know that only 3 options are available... then if it's not option 1 and also not option 2, then it must be option 3. If there are more than 3 options, you need to use your formula. But you haven't specified what to use if it also doesn't equal 3.